# Долгая загрузка Android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, эмулятор, android-emulator, avd

Вопрос в следующем: Когда я создал эмулятор устройства, он работал достаточно шустро(имеется в виду, когда не открыт ни один проект, и чисто открыт AVD). Стоит открыть проект и просто запустить приложение емулятор начинает виснуть просто безбожно и запускается нормально (Нормально работает) раза с 6-го.
Уже что только не делал:
Ставил старую версию ОС (вплоть до 4.4)
Увеличивал ОЗУ эмулятору до 4 ГБ
Включал виртуализацию.

Если важно, то процессор у меня АМД

Answer (score 1):

У меня были такие же проблемы, попробуйте использовать не эмулятор, а сам телефон через подключение с USB.

https://javatutorial.net/connect-android-device-android-studio

Можете еще отключить проверку антивирусом проектов Android Studio(это помогает, но не так значительно).
Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

А оперативы у Вас на пк сколько?

Я делаю так:
Создаю новый профиль, с такими параметрами:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда создали профиль, выбираете его в списке, наждимаете далее, выбираю API28 или 29 х86 (раньше не работал вчера создал: х86_64, теперь работает). Далее.

Задаём параметры: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если у вас норм видокарта, и нет интегрированоной, то можно видео оставить авто или Hardware, но если она слабенькая или интегрирована в проц, то в 9 из 10 будут проблемы.

Есть ещё тонкость, когда выбераете готовые профили, избегайте: GooglePlay Market. Этот img потом занимает 10+Gb и тупит не реально. И у вас не получится выбрать графику.